# w, h = template.shape[::-1] results in Value Error too many values to unpack

Tags: python, opencv

Im on `Python 2.7 (x86) ,Open CV 3.1.0, Windows 7 (x64)`

Trying some simple template matching on Open CV

**The image**

[image]

**The code**

```
dark_elixir_sample = cv2.imread('dark_elixir_sample.png')

w, h = dark_elixir_sample.shape[::-1]
```

I'm trying to get `w,h` for further usage in my script, however the script returns the following error.

**The error**

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Just print `.shape` and see what values are in there.

Comment: This: `[::-1]` reverses the array, you are looking for `[:-1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your image shape returns 3 dimensions

```
im.shape
>>> (24, 28, 3)
```

If you only want the first 2 do:

```
w, h = im.shape[:-1]
>>> (24, 28)
```

or

```
w, h, _ = im.shape
# w is 24, h is 28
```

Because otherwise, you are trying to unpack 3 values into only 2 variables, that won't work in Python hence your error. The `_` is like [a convention in Python for variables you don't want to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python), or a "throwaway".

Answer (score 0):

```
dark_elixir_sample = cv2.imread('dark_elixir_sample.png',0)
w, h = dark_elixir_sample.shape[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing

`w, h = im.shape`

what is happening-

`w, h = imageHeight,imageWidth, number` (3 for rgb, 2 for gray)

solution

`w, h, _ = in.shape[::-1]`

or convert into gray image